# gridding extraction in image

Tags: c#, image-processing, grid

There is an image, and there are some grid lines which are vertical or horizontal in the image. I just want to extract the gridding from the image, but there are many unnecessary lines in the image, interfering my work. Do anyone have a more methods to extract the gridding via C#?

My idea is that for grid lines, there are some basic unit that compose the whole gridding, so if I know the size of the basic unit and I know the initial point of the gridding, maybe I can re-draw the gridding. Thus, I think it is the key to resolve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'extract the gridding'? Do you want to remove it to get an image without the grid or do you __really__ want to 'extract' it and get the grid without the image?

Comment: @TaW I want to extract it and get an image that only has gridding.

Comment: I see. But without seeing a typical example image I can't even begin to think about a good way to detect the grid lines. But yes, re-drawing them will probably be easier and nicer than copying pixels from a source..

Comment: Please link to an example image.

Comment: @TaW I am limited to post a image, maybe I can send it to your email

Comment: @user3919259: goto http://tinypic.com/ works fine. You can post the url you get there here.

Comment: @RobAu Sorry it is said I cannot post an image because I am new and the reputation in stalkoverflow is lower than 10. Maybe I can send to your email or via other methods?

Comment: @TaW [link](http://i58.tinypic.com/debozq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two direction you can take:

- Either you take a look at the image and draw a grid just like the one there
- Or you try to analyze the image to find out the parameters it takes to draw thw grid

I loaded the image into Photoshop and found that the gridlines start at (6,10) with a raster of 43 pixels and a line width of 1.5-2 pixels.

Using these values to draw those lines is trivial:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(yourImage);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp) )
using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkBlue, 2f) )
{
    G.Clear(Color.Black);
    for (int x = 6; x  < img.Width; x += 43)
        G.DrawLine(pen, x, 0, x, img.Height);
    for (int y = 10; y  < img.Height; y += 43)
        G.DrawLine(pen, 0, y, img.Width, y);
}
bmp.Save(yourGrid);
bmp.Dispose();
img.Dispose();
```

The second option is not trivial. If the image is in fact typical, the good news is that the lines are straight and the raster regular. But pulling those values from the image automagically is still not so simple. One dificulty id the varying color of the grid.. I would scan a number of rows and test the pixels for being not black. Those would go into lists and then I would discard points that are only in a minority of those lists. This would then be repeated for a number of columns.

The effort to put into this will only pay if you need this analysis to be done for a considerable number of files with different grids. If the number is small a semi-automatic analysis may be easier and if it is only about one file go for the manual analysis!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I have explaint something wrong. The image I load is not the original image I get, but the intermediate result I get. And the color is drawed by myself, thus, no matter which color the pixel is, the only thing for me is to get the information of the gridding, and re-draw the gridding. Also, I cannot get the start point of the lines using Photoshop or other tools because I want to extract the lines automatically. Thus, it means that I only write code in c# and after running the code, I may get the gridding.

Comment: _The image I load is not the original image I get, but the intermediate result I get_ I don't understand. How is this _intermediate result_ created? Depending on the details you may need to look for a __pattern recognition__ library..